# Old Community wiki Answer not an answer

Tags: support, review, community-wiki

Reviewing old posts, I came across [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/163368/128794).  My first inclination was to flag, not an answer.  The designation as a community wiki threw me though.

Here's the answer:

> So, after I create my VM with Fusion from my bootcamp partition, I will then have the option to either run windows through Fusion or to reboot and run windows natively off my bootcamp partition? I just want to make sure that I don't lose the latter option once I install the VM Fusion. Thanks!!

Should it be flagged not an answer, nonetheless?  I'm thinking the wiki designation was interpreted a bit differently back then was it not?

Answer (score 3):

I assume at the time you were able to set something as CW even as an unregistered user.

Either way, it should not stop you from flagging.

Comment: Thanks... done and done :)